# Java javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, stax

I use stax to control xml file :

```
 XMLStreamReader dataXML = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));

            while (dataXML.hasNext())
            {
                int type = dataXML.next();
                switch(type)
                {
                    case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                        System.out.println(getLocalName());
                        break;

                    case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
                        System.out.println(dataXML.getText());
                        break;
                }
```

I have this error when I try to run :

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

EDIT :
XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
```

Comment: Looks like there is something in your XML file that the parser does not understand. Please include your XML in your question.

Comment: @jpllosa I just edit my post with first lines of my xml (I can't include my xml file : 50mb)

Comment: No need to show the entire file. Just the relevant parts. Start tag, end tag. A couple of fake data in the middle. Have you tried removing the `Main` tag? Perhaps the parser does not understand the `xmlns` attributes.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the first character in the file is "<". No leading newlines, for example? Check it with a hex editor. Another popular cause of this error is reading the wrong file.